# ASP.NET CustomValidator with ClientValidationFunction

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

I'm trying to validate an integer range with a CustomValidator. The range is set dynamically, so when either the min/max values on my usercontrol change, the client validation function is updated. However, I can't get the validation function to fire. I have this code:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="vldAnswerValid" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAnswer" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="answer" OnServerValidate="vldAnswerValid_ServerValidate" Enabled='<%# !IsReadOnly %>' />
```

Setting the function from the codebehind with:

```
vldAnswerValid.ClientValidationFunction = " function(oSrc, args){ alert(1); args.IsValid = false; } ";
```

But there's no message displayed and no alert. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Set [EnableClientScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript.aspx) property to True.